# Delphi XE always "Find Text at Cursor"?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Is it just me, or does Delph XE (Pro, Update 1) always "Find Text at Cursor" even if that option is turned off?

Comment: I QC'd this at:  http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=92388

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug, I have the same behavior for Delphi XE Enterprise, Update 1.  The help states:

> When this option is disabled you must type in the search text, **unless the Text To Find list box is blank**, in which case the editor still inserts the text at the cursor. The default is On.

But my text to find list box is not empty at the moment.  You shall report it to QC.

Comment: Wow! This is almost a reason to stick with 2010. I truly hate Find at cursor.

Comment: @David, on the bright side, the entire text is selected, meaning if you start typing it's wiped out. I actually like the behavior myself.

Comment: @Ken On the not so bright side, what I had searched for last time has been over-written. That's my objection. My work flow often involves search, F3, F3, pause, think, look around, search, F3, F3. Perhaps with the new inline search the second CTRL+F is spurious and F3 will continue my interrupted search.

Comment: @David, F3 will continue your last search. There's also a list of previous searches maintained in the find dialog (in a combobox) that you can retrieve. (This is in D2007, too.)

Comment: IMO it is the list of previous searches that's borken in XE. Back in the times of the dialog box, search history was shown in reverse chronological order. Now it's alphabetical and very long, making it extremely hard to quickly repeat the previous search. (With Find Text at Cursor the current text replaces your previous search pattern, so good luck finding it in the list. What used to take a single down-arrow click is now too hard to bother.) A minor annoyance, but repeated dozens of times a day it kinda grows.

Comment: F3 is ok if I don't want to change my search options (case sensitive, whole word, etc.).  I'm thinking of going back to Delphi 2010.  (Seperate topic, but I can't get the help system in Delphi XE to work either.  Keep getting Access Violations!)